# How to pair row for arrival and departure

Tags: sql-server

```
FPL_ID  AFSKEY  FLIGHTNO FLIGHTYPE  STAD                   AIRCRAFTTYPECODE TAILNO STANDCODE

1733285 4383931 UL 0314   A        2014-01-01 05:35:00.000  A343             4RADC  C015
1733554 4382525 UL 0315   D        2014-01-01 08:25:00.000  A343             4RADC  C015
1733385 4382929 AK 5107   A    2014-01-01 07:00:00.000  A320         9MAFB  F086
1733484 4381571 AK 5212   D    2014-01-01 07:25:00.000  A320         9MAFB  F086
```

I need help.
How to pair base on FLIGHTYPE A=Arrival and D=Departure into a single row ?

Comment: thank zerkms,but how to skip if the pair if wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just inner join the same table again. In the example below, `f1` will contain arrivals and `f2` departures.

```
select f1.*, f2.*  -- replace with the list of columns you need
from flights f1
inner join flighs f2 
    on f1.FLIGHTNO = f2.FLIGHTNO
    and f1.FPL_ID <> f2.FPL_ID
    and f1.FLIGHTYPE = 'A' and f2.FLIGHTYPE = 'D'
```

Comment: suppose the tailno to be equal for arrival and departure but sometimes it can be wrong between date and time

Comment: It's a bit vague but you should be able to achieve that by adding more conditions to the existing join conditions.